# Which study design of R survey package to use with NAMCS dataset?

Tags: r, stata, survey, sas

From official dataset documentation:

```
SAS - PROC SURVEYMEANS
PROC SURVEYMEANS DATA=TEST;
CLUSTER CPSUM;
STRATA CSTRATM;


Stata - For use with ultimate cluster design option:
The pweight (PATWT), strata (CSTRATM), and PSU (CPSUM) are set with the svyset command as follows:
Stata 8:
svyset [pweight=patwt], psu(cpsum) strata(cstratm)
Stata 9 and later:
svyset cpsum [pweight=patwt], strata(cstratm)
```

more here at Appendix I: ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Dataset_Documentation/NAMCS/doc2016.pdf

I need to analyze NAMCS with R survey package. For svydesign I use following code:

```
svydesign(ids=~CPSUM, strata = ~CSTRATM, weights = ~PATWT, data=all_vars_ready)
```

**QUESTION:** Is my svydesign code appropriate to use with NAMCS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that matches the Stata specification